# Capacitor IC layout

Tags: integrated-circuit, layout

What is the reason behind this connection of the plates of capacitors  in layout?

Why is one of the plates was formed by 2 metal layers?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A capacitor has two plates.

Your structure has two metal regions:
[image]

The metal I circled in red is one plate. All the metal I circled in green is the other plate.

By interleaving the plates this way you get more capacitance from a given die area than you would by just using one layer for the 2nd plate.

Discrete capacitors often use a similar interleaved structure. Here's a typical aluminum electrolytic type:

[image]

([source](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Gautam_Biswas3/publication/241195108/figure/fig1/AS:298554691211264@1448192393063/Construction-of-Electrolytic-Capacitor-1.png))

And here's a typical multilayer ceramic type (illustrating why small cracks can short the plates):

[image]

([source](https://ndiastorage.blob.core.usgovcloudapi.net/ndia/2011/fuze/SessionIIIAOMalley.pdf))

Answer (score 1):

In general, using N layers of dielectric (and N+1 layers of metal) gives you N times the capacitance in a given amount of chip surface area.

There are other ways of creating capacitors on ICs — for example, between metal and substrate. or across a reverse-biased diode junction. These can give you more capacitance in a given area (important in applications like DRAM), but are less well-controlled in terms of the exact value of capacitance you get.

Answer (score 1):

In certain capacitive applications, such as highly-monotonic low-INL ADCs, the quality of the oxide/dielectric and thus the dielectric-absorption are key params.

The foundary may have determined the metal-metal, using the available oxides, were the best for ADC performance, thus that stackup of metal and insulation characterized and included in the design manual.